# WPF: IEditableCollectionView and CanAddNew and empty collections

Tags: wpf, ieditablecollectionview

We were having some issues with the wpf datagrid and IEditableCollectionView (although this question applies to using IEditableCollectionView and ItemsControl) When you have a collection with no items in it, the IEditableCollectionView cannot determine what items should be inserted so it sets `CanAddNew=false` we found a solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/27/using-ieditablecollectionview-with-dynamically-generated-gridviewcolumns.aspx) (buried deep in the comments) that goes like so :

If you derive from ObservableCollection like this

```
public class PersonsList : ObservableCollection<Person> { }
```

you will find out that if the initial collection is empty, there won't be a NewItemPlaceHolder showing up on the view. That's because PersonsList cannot resolve type T at design time. A workaround that works for me is to pass type T as a parameter into the class like this

```
PersonsList<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : Person { }
```

This approach will place the NewItemPlaceHolder even if the collection is empty.

I'm wondering if there is an interface i can implement on my collections that inform the IEditableCollectionView which type to create should i get an AddNew request.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `IEditableObject` on `T` and see if the problem goes away. [Vincent Sibal](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/11/05/wpf-datagrid-new-item-template-sample.aspx) says this is necessary. But he also claims `PersonsList<T>` is also needed, but you figured this out already. Hopefully, `IEditableObject` is enough and you'd be able to use non-generic class.